# Boosting monster companion

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, animal-companions

Im playing a 9th Beast Heart Adept with a couple of dips into other classes and i wanna know if there's any feat or magical items of the sort that boost the minions that Beast Heart Adept get since it apparently does not stack with other class-levels that give you animal companion, so here's my questions.

1. So is there anything that boosts animals from Beast heart adept?
2. Is there any items that boost hd of either animal companions or just boost hd in general?

Comment: I think a better definition of *boost* is needed here. I mean, for example, you could always just strap masterwork or magical studded leather armor on the creatures to boost their ACs, for instance, but I suspect you want something else. Do you mean, like, a magic item that raise the character's effective druid level or a magic elixir that grants permanent extra Hit Dice (neither exist, by the way) or something else?

Comment: Boosting the animal companion via feats or magical items that raise their hd or boost animal companion in general

Answer (score 0):

Obnoxiously, the beast heart adept’s monster companions are explicitly distinct from animal companions and do not stack with things that count towards animal companions. This is a problem because pretty much *nothing* references monster companions, while animal companions have a ton of options. That leaves only two options: uncanny trickster from *Complete Scoundrel*, and legacy champion from *Weapons of Legacy*. These advance **any** class feature, so that should include beast heart adept. This would improve your extra monster companions, as well as your primary one if you chose one of the more powerful monsters that applies a penalty on your effective level. After finishing beast heart adept (and having five levels in whatever to qualify for it), you have five levels remaining. If all five are levels in legacy champion, you would count as a 14th-level beast heart adept. Please note that legacy champion is a pretty awful class aside from this, and really, *Weapons of Legacy* is a really awful book.

Beyond those, at best, you can ask your DM if he would be willing to houserule some or all of these to work with monster companions as well as animal companions:

- Natural Bond (*Complete Adventurer*)—a feat for +3 to your effective druid level for animal companions. Getting +3 to each of your monster companions is a decent use of a feat.
- Beastmaster (*Complete Adventurer*)—stacks with druid levels for animal companions, *on top of a +3 bonus*. So, in theory, if applied to a beast heart adept, you could be a 10th-level beast heart adept/1st-level beastmaster, and count as a “14th-level” beast heart adept for the purposes of your monsters.
- Devoted Tracker (*Complete Adventurer*)—if you can summon a paladin special mount, you can treat it as your animal companion, gaining the benefits of both. This is less useful here, since it starts with the special mount, so at best that special animal would replace your monster. Still, if allowed, you could apply the bonuses you would apply to a monster companion to your special mount.

  - Halfling outrider (*Complete Warrior*)—advances both special companion and animal companions. If they’re one and the same, that’s some serious advancement. Moreover, if allowed to apply to beast heart adept, it would also improve your other two monster companions.
  - High One warrior wizard ([*Champions of Valor* web enhancement](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060327a))—requires 2 levels of paladin, but it basically allows you to use your special mount to be your familiar. If that special mount-familiar is *also* a monster companion, that is going to be one tough beast.
- Arcane hierophant (*Races of the Wild*)—allows you to make your animal companion *also* your familiar, and stacks with levels for both. Unfortunately, even for animal companions, explicitly states that you’re only allowed to retain one animal companion, which makes it a really dubious choice.